# PatoolError Python: problem in unpacking .rar file

Tags: python, rar, unrar

I can't unpack a .rar file using patoolib in Python.
I always get the error message:

PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z),

I'm using macOS, Anaconda Navigator with Spyder IDE, and I have already installed unrar package. I don't understand why patool can't find the executable program and I'm not able to solve this problem.

Can someone tell me how to solve?

EDIT:

The error arises when I call this method, that I defined to unpack both .zip and .rar files:

```py
def unzip_file(path_to_file, out_dir):
    # Extracts path_to_file in out_dir
    if path_to_file[-3:] == 'zip':
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(out_dir)
            return
    if path_to_file[-3:] == 'rar':
        patoolib.extract_archive(path_to_file, outdir=out_dir)    
        return
    
    raise FileNotFoundError(path_to_file)
```

Comment: You need to shows us what you have tried...

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: ```python  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 684, in extract_archive   return _extract_archive(archive, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, outdir=outdir, program=program)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 470, in _extract_archive program = find_archive_program(format, 'extract', program=program)```

Answer (score 0):

You're on macOS, you should probably install[Homebrew](https://brew.sh) if it's not installed, and then run `brew install 7z` and try again.

I'm guessing that this tool you're using doesn't do the actual archiving, it just knows how to talk to the various archive programs out there, and so you need to have installed one that can read and write `RAR` archives.

Comment: Thank you. I've already installed Homebrew and 7z. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does your 7z support RAR?  I don't know this tool at all, but there's a little clause about that right here https://github.com/wummel/patool/blob/master/patoolib/__init__.py#L345

Comment: This patool doesn't seem very well-documented.  You might do better just installing unrar   and writing your own shell commands in the python program, so that you have better control.  Sometimes (often) using somebody else's tool can un-simplify things accidentally.

Comment: @TylerGannon _This patool doesn't seem very well-documented. You might do better just installing unrar and writing your own shell commands in the python program, so that you have better control._ It also seems to be unmaintained.

Comment: There you have it.